Spread a ClickHouse map as columns
I have a ClickHouse table with a tags column of type Map(String, String).
When exporting this data, I'd like to explode the tags map into columns. For example if I had in row 1 tags: {"key1":"value1"} and in row 2 tags: {"key5": "value75"} there should be two columns in the exported table called key1 and key5. Missing values should just be null. The tags map can contain arbitrary values.
How can I achieve this in ClickHouse?

one approach is to list all the distinct keys, then get all their values by map. But single lookup would take linear complexity. Wondering what would be a better solution. But why use a Map?

We use a map since the tags / number of tags is arbitrary, so we can't have a schema that accounts for them ahead of time, just at read time we want to have them appear as columns (and only for one specific read case)

Better make it on application side
SQL is suboptimal choice to make dynamic column names depends on returning data
because it requires a full scan whole result before sending the first row of result
